# Upgraded RDS Postgres and did not know DMS was not supported

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am panicking slightly and need some help please, I have looked online and I am still struggling. We recently upgraded our Postgres version on RDS from 11 to 16.1 as AWS was stopping support for version 11.

Read the postgres release notes and everything seemed fine. However we have a DMS task to move data from RDS to redshift, here comes the problem... DMS does not support postgres 16.1

I looked at potentially downgrading as a last resort but RDS does not even offer this. So now I am looking to get a dump from our DB and restore that dump on a downgraded RDS instance, however when I try dump I get the following error:

```
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: detail: server version: 16.1; pg_dump version: 15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg18.04+1).
```

The problem here is that AWS manage this.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated

Comment: An alternative approach is to use [Federated queries to PostgreSQL - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/getting-started-federated.html) to extract the data directly from the Postgres database. Could work out a lot cheaper than using AWS DMS, too.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, that actually looks like a more suitable solution as the data will be live. 

I just have some questions on this: 

1. It seems like these federated queries are more for querying data, is using them to copy data from RDS to Redshift more of a hack or is it the intended use?

2. We don't really want a heavy load on our production DB, so would a read replica work in this instance?

Comment: You could use [CREATE TABLE AS - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html) with a query that selects from the Postgres database. Or, use an existing table with `TRUNCATE` and then `INSERT INTO`. Yes, you could pull the information from a Read Replica. Let us know how it goes!